# How to fix "Segmentation fault" in fortran program

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I wrote this program that reads daily gridded climate model data (6 variables) from a file and uses it in further calculations. When running the pgm for a relatively short period (e.g. 5 years) it works fine, but when I want to run it for the required 30 year period I get a "Segmentation fault".

System description: Lenovo Thinkpad with Core i7 vPro with Windows 10 Pro
Program run in Fedora (64-bit) inside Oracle VM VirtualBox

After commenting out everything and checking section-by-section I found that:

1. everything works fine for 30 years as long as it reads 4 variables only
2. as soon as the 5th or 6th variable is added, the problem creeps in
3. alternatively, I can run it with all 6 variables but then it only works for a shorter analysis period (e.g. 22 years)

So the problem might lie with:

- the statement: recl=AX*AY*4   which I borrowed from another pgm, yet changing the 4 doesn't fix it
- the system I'm running the pgm on

I have tried the "ulimit -s unlimited" command suggested elsewhere, but only get the response "cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted".

File = par_query.h

```
  integer AX,AY,startyr,endyr,AT
  character pperiod*9,GCM*4

  parameter(AX=162,AY=162)          ! dim of GCM array
  parameter(startyr=1961,endyr=1990,AT=endyr-startyr+1,
 &          pperiod="1961_1990")
  parameter(GCM='ukmo')
```

File = query.f

```
  program query
  !# A FORTRAN program that reads global climate model (GCM) data to 
  !# be used in further calculations
  !# uses parameter file: par_query.h
  !# compile as: gfortran -c -mcmodel=large query.f
  !#             gfortran query.o
  !# then run: ./a.out

  ! Declarations ***************************************************
  implicit none
  include 'par_query.h'    ! parameter file
  integer :: i,j,k,m,n,nn,leapa,leapb,leapc,leapn,rec1,rec2,rec3,
 &           rec4,rec5,rec6
  integer, dimension(12) :: mdays
  real :: ydays,nyears
  real, dimension(AX,AY,31,12,AT) :: tmax_d,tmin_d,rain_d,rhmax_d,
 &                                   rhmin_d,u10_d
  character :: ipath*43,fname1*5,fname2*3,nname*14,yyear*4,mmonth*2,
 &             ext1*4

  ! Data statements and defining characters ************************
  data mdays/31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31/   ! Days in month  
  ydays=365.                                        ! Days in year
  nyears=real(AT)                ! Analysis period (in years)
  ipath="/run/media/stephan/SS_Elements/CCAM_africa/" ! Path to 
                                 ! input data directory
  fname1="ccam_"                 ! Folder where data is located #1       
  fname2="_b/"                   ! Folder where data is located #2
  nname="ccam_africa_b."         ! Input filename (generic part)
  ext1=".dat"
  leapa=0
  leapb=0
  leapc=0
  leapn=0

  ! Read daily data from GCM ***************************************
  do n=startyr,endyr    ! Start looping through years --------------
    write(yyear,'(i4.4)')n
    nn=n-startyr+1
    ! Test for leap years
    leapa=mod(n,4)
    leapb=mod(n,100)
    leapc=mod(n,400)
    if (leapa==0) then
      if (leapb==0) then
        if (leapc==0) then
          leapn=1
        else
          leapn=0
        endif
      else
        leapn=1
      endif
    else
      leapn=0
    endif
    if (leapn==1) then
      mdays(2)=29
      ydays=366.
    else
      mdays(2)=28
      ydays=365.
    endif
    do m=1,12    ! Start looping through months -------------------- 
      write(mmonth,'(i2.2)')m
      ! Reading daily data from file
      print*,"Reading data for ",n,mmonth
      open(101,file=ipath//fname1//GCM//fname2//nname//GCM//"."//
 &             yyear//mmonth//ext1,access='direct',recl=AX*AY*4)
      do k=1,mdays(m)    ! Start looping through days --------------
        rec1=(k-1)*6+1
        rec2=(k-1)*6+2
        rec3=(k-1)*6+3
        rec4=(k-1)*6+4
        rec5=(k-1)*6+5
        rec6=(k-1)*6+6
        read(101,rec=rec1)((tmax_d(i,j,k,m,nn),i=1,AX),j=1,AY)
        read(101,rec=rec2)((tmin_d(i,j,k,m,nn),i=1,AX),j=1,AY)
        read(101,rec=rec3)((rain_d(i,j,k,m,nn),i=1,AX),j=1,AY)
        read(101,rec=rec4)((rhmax_d(i,j,k,m,nn),i=1,AX),j=1,AY)
        read(101,rec=rec5)((rhmin_d(i,j,k,m,nn),i=1,AX),j=1,AY)
        read(101,rec=rec6)((u10_d(i,j,k,m,nn),i=1,AX),j=1,AY)
      enddo    ! k-loop (days) ends --------------------------------
      close(101)
    enddo    ! m-loop (months) ends --------------------------------
  enddo    ! n-loop (years) ends -----------------------------------

  end program query
```

Comment: Please try to compile with debug options, especially with boundary checking. What are the current setting of your limits. Also the arrays (6) with `(AX,AY,31,12,AT)` might be a bit large for your memory settings.

Comment: Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Get used to compile your codes with all debugging options your compiler offers. Turn them off only when the program is tested and you need it to run faster. These options can be `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` or `gfortran -g -fsanitize=address,undefined`. Please recompile the code with these options and use them in the future. Report back with the output of the program with these options. All my data processing programs are compiled with these options even for serious work.

Comment: Also, always report the complete output of the program, not just the last two error words. Usually there is more and it can help to locate the error.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I thought I did use the fortran tag - my bad.

Comment: So do I use this command line on the .f or .o file? Upon entering "gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all query.f" I get the long list of "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'" messages. Upon entering "gfortran -c -mcmodel=large query.f" followed by "gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all query.o" and "./a.out" I really only get the one line message: "Segmentation fault".

Comment: gfortran -g -fsanitize=address,undefined query.f
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libasan.so.5.0.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It seems that there was no problem in the code itself. I managed to increase Virtual Box's "Base Memory" and the program ran without any error messages.